# How to prove that those limits are equal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

let $\lim a_n = a$ and $\lim b_n = b$. We define two groups:-

Group A:- Includes all the elements that imply $a_n>b_n$.All the elements in $a_n$ that are bigger than the the elements in $b_n$.

Group B:- Includes all the elements that imply $b_n>a_n$.All the elements in $b_n$ that are bigger than the the elements in $a_n$.

Also it is known that both groups are NOT bounded.
I need to prove that $a=b$.
Never met these kinds of questions so hope you can give me some advice on how to solve it because I tried to solve it using the definition of the limit but it didnt work out well.

Comment: Hint: by symmetry, it suffices to prove that $a\ge b$, i.e. $\lim a_n \ge b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \neq b$. Without loss of generality assume that $a>b$. Choose $\epsilon = \dfrac{a-b}2$. Since $a_n \to a$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$,
$$a-\epsilon < a_n < a + \epsilon$$
Similarly, since $b_n \to b$, there exists $M$ such that for all $n>M$,
$$b-\epsilon < b_n < b + \epsilon$$
Hence, for $K = \max(N,M)$, we obtain that for all $n>K$, we have
$$b_n < b+\epsilon = a-\epsilon < a_n$$
This gives us that for all $n>K$, we have $a_n > b_n$, which means that $B$ is a finite set contradicting the fact that $B$ is an infinite set.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction $a < b$. Then for $n$ big enough you have
$$a_n < b_n$$
i.e. $\{ n : a_n > b_n\}$ is bounded. But this contradicts your assumption. So $a \ge b$.

In the same way you prove that $b \ge a$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following:

$A=\{ n  :   a_n > b_n\}$    (i.e. the set of indices where $a_n > b_n$)

$B= \{ n  :  \ a_n > b_n\}$    (i.e. the set of indices where $b_n > a_n$)

That said, this sounds like HW problem from a real analysis class, so I will only give a hint:  Assume that $a > b.$    Let $\epsilon = 0.5(b-a)$ and choose $N$ sufficiently large that $n>N$ implies $|a_n - a|< \epsilon$ and $|b_n - b| < \epsilon.$    This will lead to a contradiction of your assumption about $A$ and $B$.